# qtranslate-x problem with custom term description

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, terms, plugin-qtranslate

I use qtranslate-x plugin for site translation.
Works well, but on my custom term's page I see description in all languages.
[image]

I use this code to display term information:

```
$term = $wp_query->queried_object;
echo '<h1>'. $term->name . '</h1>';
echo '<p>' . $term->description . '</p>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo term_description( $term->term_id, $taxonomy );
```